# Django: include a url with no namespace

Tags: django, django-urls

I have an a Django app, with respect to the project root at `applib/hw/apps.py`
The `name` attribute of the config class within this `apps.py` is `applib.hw`.

The app controls how a user is logged in. I wish it's urls to its own app `url.py` so its modular, but it fails:

```py
# applib/hw/urls.py

url_patterns = [
    path('accounts/login/', UserLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('version/', views.version_view, name='version'),
]
```

This fails because then the login name for reversal is `applib.hw.login`, whereas Django expects just `login`

I can not place it in the project's `url.py` because it is an optional Django app, and if it is installed, then the apps urls are automatically prepended to the project URLS (so its found first).

Comment: you can add `app_name = 'applibhw'` in your `urls.py`, then you can refer to it with `applibhw:login`.

Comment: if this is truly a login page, you could try setting `LOGIN_URL='/accounts/login/`